Is $R=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : | x|<|y| \text { or } x=y\}$ a total order on $\mathbb{R}$?

Suppose $A=\mathbb{R}$ and $R=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} : | x|<|y| \text { or } x=y\}$ is defined on $A$. Is $R$ a total order on $A$?

I was able to show that $R$ is a partial order on $A$. If $R$ is a total order, then: $\forall x, y \in A \ (x R y \ \text{or} \ y R x)$. To prove the previous statement, I reason as follows:
Choose $x, y \in A$. Clearly, if $x = y$, then $x R y$. Now suppose that $x \ne y$. [I am stuck at this point.]
Is it true that if $x \ne y$, then $|x| < |y|$ or $|y| < |x|$, and, therefore, $x R y$, and, therefore, $R$ is a total order?

No. It is not true.

@CameronBuie, can you please provide a counterexample?

"Is it true that if ≠, then ||<|| or ||<||?". This is already not true and a counterexample to this gives a counterexample.

I could provide all infinitely-many of them, but it would be better for you if you first consider what $\lvert x\rvert$ means, so that you can come up with them, yourself.

Surely you can come up with two distinct real numbers that have the same absolute value, right?

@Vlad: can $+1$ and $-1$ be compared in the given Order?
